# Constantly refreshing UIImage

Tags: java, ios, sockets, server

I am trying to send an image to an iOS app from a Java client. I need to send the image as fast as possible to get high fps. I tried using sockets but it was too slow, so now I am uploading to a server from the client and downloading it with the app. This works when using a java receiver, but not on the app. When viewed on the app the image just comes up black, because the image is being saved again and again. In java the image refreshes and you can see the frames, but in iOS its just always black. Is there anyway I can fix this? Or do I need to find a better way to transfer the image? Thanks!

My Upload Code:

```
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, img.getType());
    Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g.dispose();
    return dimg;
}

public void uploadToServer() {

    String server = "ip";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "user";
    String pass = "pass";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int w = 765;
        int h = 503;
        double d = .75;

        ImageIO.write(
                resize(client.methods.getClientImage(), (int) (w * d),
                        (int) (h * d)), "JPG", os);

        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());

        String secondRemoteFile = "public_html/iRS/client_img.jpg";

        // System.out.println("Start uploading file");
        OutputStream outputStream = ftpClient
                .storeFileStream(secondRemoteFile);

        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
        int read = 0;

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        ftpClient.completePendingCommand();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
                Tools.log("Disconnected");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Download code:

```
- (void) refreshImage {
        client.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"url"]]]; ;
}
```

Comment: Save to temporary files instead of continually overwriting the same file.

Comment: I just tried uploading the image only once, to see if I am uploading correctly and it saves with a purple tint which leads me to believe I am not saving it correctly. I will post my code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store in a file if you just need it for a couple of millisecs.
Download the file to an NSData and pass that to a UIImage.
Here's some example code from my HTTP client class.
The following method starts a download task:

```
- (NSURLSessionTask *) startGetTaskForURL: (NSURL *) url {
    NSLog(@"startGetTaskForUrl: %@", url);
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithURL:url];
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
    [task resume];
    [self.runningTasks setObject:data forKey:task];
    return task;
}
```

The following delegate method gets called every time there is data available. The data is collected here in an NSMutableData that was created when the task was created:

```
- (void) URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"HTTPClient: Data task received data: %@", dataString);
    NSMutableData *runningData = [self dataForTask:dataTask];
    if (!runningData) {
        NSLog(@"No data found for task");
        return;
    }
    [runningData appendData: data];
}
```

The following delegate method gets called when the download task is done:

```
- (void) URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"HTTPClient: Task completed with error: %@", error);
    [self.delegate sessionTask:task completedWithError:error data:[self dataForTask:task]];
}
```

Comment: I am not the best in cocoa, could you give me more of an example of how to use this?

Comment: I posted what I use for image refresh.